# How do I run a multi-step sequence in grails shell?

Tags: grails

How do I do the following in the grails shell (with grails 2.3.8)?  (Not the grails console).

```
int x = 1
println(x)
```

When I try it, I get:

```
groovy:000> int x = 1
===> 1
groovy:000> println(x)
Unknown property: x
```

I've looked at the list of commands provided by running help in the shell, but they aren't helping so far.  The doc at https://grails.org/Command+Line+Tools indicates I should be able to type in code and then enter 'go' to run it, but that doesn't work either (and that webpage is 3 years old).

Answer (score 0):

The key was to find out that

```
grails shell
```

runs the normal groovy console, which has documentation at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell

At that page, I learned the answer to my question:

```
x = 1
println(x)
```

The only change was to drop the 'int' declaration.  When that is done, the variable becomes available for use later.